# How to Disable a calendar Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a image button in my web page as calender.png, when button is clicked it will displays date and time picker. But now i want to disable/ enable it in code behind(not in aspx.cs page) as per the dropdownlist selection. How to do it.

```
    <td>Need Duration</td>  
                <td>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
                 **<img src="Images/calender.png"/>**
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.dynDateTime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/calendar-en.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/calendar-blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                showsTime: true,
                ifFormat: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",
                daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m,  %Y",
                align: "BR",
                electric: false,
                singleClick: false,
                displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function  DisableJQueryCalendar() 
     { 
    $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').datepicker('disable'); 
     }

  function EnableJQueryCalendar()
     {  
    $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>').datepicker('enable');  
     }
</script>


protected void btnClick(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if(con==true)//When Condn true then Disable Calendar
    {
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "com", "DisableJQueryCalendar()", true);
    }
    else //enable Calendar
    {
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "com", "EnableJQueryCalendar()", true);
    }
}
```

Note:- Here ... we are try to disable the Text box not an image...because...image not containing the runat="server" property...